# ImportError: cannot import name 'lzip' from 'pandas.compat' when importing pandas_gbq

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, lzip

I try to `import pandas_gbq` on a fresh installed Anaconda. It returns this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'lzip' from 'pandas.compat'
```

My Python version is `3.9` and pandas version is `1.4.2`.

Please kindly help, just let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Install `pandas_gbq` instead of `pandas` (they are two different packages) using [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-gbq/).

It will automatically install other dependencies packages including `pandas`

```
conda activate <your-conda_env_name>
pip install pandas_gbq
```

Comment: thanks! already installed pandas_gbq on both conda and pip, still yielding same error

Comment: Could you uninstall `pandas` and `pandas_gbq` completely and reinstall `pandas_gbq` úing pip again?